# Crystal Reports grouping removes data

Tags: sql, asp.net, crystal-reports, reporting

Basicaly, when i add another item to summarize, the group is filtered.  I'd like to show 0 or nothing if there is no data for the new item i'm adding.

[Report images](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/15626152/Untitled4.jpg)

The field i'm adding is from a different table. If i add a field from the same table it seems to allow blanks

Comment: The field i'm adding is from a different table.  If i add a field from the same table it seems to allow blanks

Comment: The edit button allows you to change your question if you need to add clarifying statements. I did it for you

Comment: This question would be easier to answer if we could see the actual SQL code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are joining the tables using an INNER JOIN. you need to make this a left join.

If you're using the "Links" functionality you can use the Link Options dialog to set it to a `Left Outer Join`

If you're writing a SQL statement to join the tables you can just use a `Left Join` instead of an `inner join`